# There are 80 balls going into 40 empty spaces at random. What is the expected number of empty spaces?

Tags: probability

The right answer should be 5.28. I don't know how to approach this problem. This exercise problem is in the "Expected values of sums of random variables" section.

Comment: I think could be related with this: normal distribution experiment using a quincunx or Galton box, https://youtu.be/PfCCf7b6Vyo , wiki: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use linearity of expectation. That is, first find the probability $p$ that a given space will remain empty; then the expected number of empty spaces is $40p$.

Comment: So $p$ is the binomial $b(x=0; n=80, p = 1/80)$, which is about 0.131. When multiplied by 40 it certainly gives me 5.28. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!